# Reshaping into long form when there are no column names for certain repetition

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have a following sample dataset, and I am trying to reshape to long form using data.table package (no dplyr solution please).

```
test_data<-structure(list(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), demo_d1_alt = c(2, 
3, 4, 5), demo_d1_pre = c(5, 4, 5, 5), demo_d2_alt = c(4, 5, 
6, 7), demo_d3_alt = c(8, 9, 10, 11), demo_d3_pre = c(5, 5, 5, 
5)), .Names = c("id", "demo_d1_alt", "demo_d1_pre", "demo_d2_alt", 
"demo_d3_alt", "demo_d3_pre"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

id  demo_d1_alt demo_d1_pre demo_d2_alt demo_d3_alt demo_d3_pre
a   2   5   4   8   5
b   3   4   5   9   5
c   4   5   6   10  5
d   5   5   7   11  5
```

Following is my code and the output:

```
library(data.table)
data_long <- melt.data.table(
     setDT(test_data), id.vars = "id", 
     measure.vars = patterns(alt = "alt",
                             prec= "pre"))
data_long
    id variable alt prec
 1:  a        1   2    5
 2:  b        1   3    4
 3:  c        1   4    5
 4:  d        1   5    5
 5:  a        2   4    5
 6:  b        2   5    5
 7:  c        2   6    5
 8:  d        2   7    5
 9:  a        3   8   NA
10:  b        3   9   NA
11:  c        3  10   NA
12:  d        3  11   NA
```

My expected output is (since only for demo_d2 there is no prec)

```
data_long
    id variable alt prec
 1:  a        1   2    5
 2:  b        1   3    4
 3:  c        1   4    5
 4:  d        1   5    5
 5:  a        2   4    NA
 6:  b        2   5    NA
 7:  c        2   6    NA
 8:  d        2   7    NA
 9:  a        3   8   5
10:  b        3   9   5
11:  c        3  10   5
12:  d        3  11   5
```

Please suggest.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2575) and [a related discussion](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2551#issuecomment-358670658) for what led to my draft [`ReshapeLong_()` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/ceded54b616bdc61cb0f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to do a `melt/dcast`

```
dcast(melt(setDT(test_data), measure = patterns("d\\d+"))[,
    c("var1", "var2") := tstrsplit(variable, "_")[-1]], 
       id + var1 ~ var2, value.var = 'value')[order(var1)]
#    id var1 alt pre
# 1:  a   d1   2   5
# 2:  b   d1   3   4
# 3:  c   d1   4   5
# 4:  d   d1   5   5
# 5:  a   d2   4  NA
# 6:  b   d2   5  NA
# 7:  c   d2   6  NA
# 8:  d   d2   7  NA
# 9:  a   d3   8   5
#10:  b   d3   9   5
#11:  c   d3  10   5
#12:  d   d3  11   5
```

Comment: Thank you. So, `melt` alone can't handle it?.

Comment: @Metrics For your code to work, there should be corresponding pairwise column.  Here, we have the d3_pre at the end.  So, it thinks that is is the  pairwise column for the 'd2_alt'.  To avoid that create a column of NAs, i.e. `cbind(test_data[1:4], demo_d2_pre = NA_real_, test_data[5:6])` before converting to data.table

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked since I have only one variable to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, most R approaches don't handle these types of unbalanced datasets very neatly, but instead require you to first convert the data into a "long" format, do some transformation, and then go back into a "wide" format.  For this, I had written the `merged.stack` function as part of my "splitstackshape" package, so named because it would first `stack` related columns of data into a `list` and then `merge` them together.

The approach would be something like:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(test_data, var.stubs = c("_alt", "_pre"), sep = "var.stubs", atStart = FALSE)
#     id .time_1 _alt _pre
#  1:  a demo_d1    2    5
#  2:  a demo_d2    4   NA
#  3:  a demo_d3    8    5
#  4:  b demo_d1    3    4
#  5:  b demo_d2    5   NA
#  6:  b demo_d3    9    5
#  7:  c demo_d1    4    5
#  8:  c demo_d2    6   NA
#  9:  c demo_d3   10    5
# 10:  d demo_d1    5    5
# 11:  d demo_d2    7   NA
# 12:  d demo_d3   11    5
```

However, with the improvements that "data.table" has brought to `melt`, it made sense to revisit the approach.

The working draft can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/ceded54b616bdc61cb0f#file-melt-r), and you can load the relevant functions with:

```
source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mrdwab/ceded54b616bdc61cb0f/raw/c5a583267f8682a5afea1b551347eafdab618471/MELT.R")
```

Usage is straightforward: specify the dataset, the stubs, and whether the stubs are at the start or at the end of the variable names.

```
library(data.table)
ReshapeLong_(test_data, stubs = c(alt = "_alt", pre = "_pre"), end_stub = TRUE)
#     id variable alt pre
#  1:  a  demo_d1   2   5
#  2:  b  demo_d1   3   4
#  3:  c  demo_d1   4   5
#  4:  d  demo_d1   5   5
#  5:  a  demo_d2   4  NA
#  6:  b  demo_d2   5  NA
#  7:  c  demo_d2   6  NA
#  8:  d  demo_d2   7  NA
#  9:  a  demo_d3   8   5
# 10:  b  demo_d3   9   5
# 11:  c  demo_d3  10   5
# 12:  d  demo_d3  11   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple hack would be

```
test_data <- as.data.table(test_data)
test_data[,.NA:=NA]
melt(test_data, id='id', 
     measure = list(c('demo_d1_alt', 'demo_d2_alt', 'demo_d3_alt'),
                    c('demo_d1_pre', '.NA', 'demo_d3_pre')))
```

align the variables by hand and insert '.NA' where no observation.

If there are mulitple missing variables,

```
test_data <- as.data.table(test_data)
test_data[,.NA:=NA]
melt(test_data, id='id', 
     measure = list(c('demo_d1_alt', 'demo_d2_alt', '.NA'),
                    c('demo_d1_pre', '.NA', 'demo_d3_pre')))
```